# Derivative of the Cayley Transform.

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry

Given $V$ a finite dimensional vector space, let $R=\{f \in  \operatorname{End}(V) : I+f \text{ is invertible}\}.$ We define the Cayley Transform $T$ such that $T: R \to  \operatorname{End}(V)$ and $T(f) = (1-f)(1+f)^{-1}$. I am asked to show that the Cayley Transform is differentiable and to find its derivative. I've already showed that the Cayley Transform is an involution but I don't know how to use this to show that its differentiable.

I am trying to use the definition of differentiable but all I get is that $T(f+h) = (I-(f+h))(I+(f+h))^{-1}$ and I don't know what to do next

Comment: @JeanMarie p. 128 is not available online or at least I wasn't able to find it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't validate this as an answer : it's just the copy of p. 128 of "Geometric Numerical Integration" E. Hairer C. Lubich G. Wanner, where the enlarged context is Cayley transform between a Lie group and its Lie algebra.

[image]

Comment: One must add that this derivative has much in common with the differential of ordinary real valued function $f$ defined by $f(x)=\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}$ which is $df=2\frac{dx}{(1-x)^2}=2(1-x)^{-1}dx(1-x)^{-1}$.